# Why solving this first order ode has an integral in the answer?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working through first-order ODE questions in my textbook and came across this problem that I believe I'm supposed to solve with the integrating method; however, I got stuck integrating and am not sure if I'm using the wrong method or if I'm misunderstanding the method. Any help would be appreciated!

[The Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6xg1.png)

[The Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ynxe.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are only showing a IVP and a textbook answer, you mention that you have tried something, but you don't show us. How can we help you check your work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your textbook simply left the integral as is, may be because it needs special function to be able to solve it (non-elementary integral). Nothing really wrong with that.

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=e^{-x^{2}-2x}%
$$
This is linear first order ode. The integrating factor is $I=e^{\int
2dx}=e^{2x}$. Hence the above becomes

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(  Iy\right)    & =Ie^{-x^{2}-2x}\\
d\left(  Iy\right)    & =\left(  Ie^{-x^{2}-2x}\right)  dx
\end{align*}

Integrating

\begin{align}
\int d\left(  Iy\right)    & =\int Ie^{-x^{2}-2x}dx\nonumber\\
Iy  & =\int e^{2x}e^{-x^{2}-2x}dx+c\nonumber\\
e^{2x}y  & =\int e^{-x^{2}}dx+c\nonumber\\
y  & =e^{-2x}\int e^{-x^{2}}dx+ce^{-2x}\nonumber\\
& =e^{-2x}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-s^{2}}ds+ce^{-2x}\tag{1}
\end{align}

At $y\left(  0\right)  =3$ the above becomes

$$
3=c
$$

Therefore (1) becomes

\begin{align*}
y  & =e^{-2x}\int^{x}e^{-s^{2}}ds+3e^{-2x}\\
& =e^{-2x}\left(  3+\int_{0}^{x}e^{-s^{2}}ds\right)
\end{align*}

Your book stopped here. But the integral can be evaluated if needed. From tables you see this is defined as special function

$\int_{0}^{x}e^{-s^{2}} ds=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}\operatorname{erf}\left(
x\right)  $. The above becomes

\begin{align*}
y  & =e^{-2x}\left(  3+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}\operatorname{erf}\left(
x\right)  \right)  \\
& =\frac{1}{2}e^{-2x}\left(  6+\sqrt{\pi}\operatorname{erf}\left(  x\right)
\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: How did you integrate the part right above (1)? I don't believe I've seen that before.

Comment: @JoshuaWang you can always write $\int f(x)\,dx$ as $\int_0^{x} f(s) \, ds$ if this is what you asking about. The stuff above that, is just standard first order solving using an integrating factor. (used to solve linear first order ode's)